# How can I go to next item of array in Angularjs expression?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have been trying to dynamically change the array number of my expression. My initial state:

```
<p class="title text-center">{{data[0].title}}</p>
<p class="subtitle text-center">{{data[0].sub_title}}</p>
```

`Data` is just an array returned from an `http` request. What I want is that when I click or swipe an element on the page that it jumps to the second item in the data array, e.g.:

```
  <p class="title text-center">{{data[1].title}}</p>
  <p class="subtitle text-center">{{data[1].sub_title}}</p>
```

I have been trying to make an expression in an expression, but I think that that is very wrong. Also, I have tried adding a variable to the `$scope` in the controller:

```
$scope.update = function (whateverispassedinfromotherfunction){
  var item = whateverispassedinfromotherfunction;

  return "data["+whateverispassedinfromotherfunction+"].sub_title";

}
```

and then this in the HTML

```
<p class="subtitle text-center">{{update}}</p>
```

but that does not make any sense to Angular and to me neither :).

Anyone that knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your current index a variable, initted to 0, and increment it. You can increment either by making a function on your controller that increments it, or just directly in a ng-click / ng-swipe.

```
<span ng-click="idx++"> <!-- init idx to 0 in your controller -->
    <p class="title text-center">{{data[idx].title}}</p>
    <p class="subtitle text-center">{{data[idx].sub_title}}</p>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works and easy to implement. Sometimes the solution is easier than one might think :)

Answer (score 1):

Dylan's answer will work, but generally when you find the need for this kind of logic, you should try to wrap it up into a more general component.

For example, we'll call it Lense, as it's just a way of viewing one value at a time, given an collection of sequential values.

```
app.factory('Lense', function() {
  return function(values) {
    var lense = {};

    lense.index = 0;

    lense.next = function() {
      lense.index += 1;
    };

    lense.previous = function() {
      lense.index -= 1;
    };

    lense.value = function() {
      return values[lense.index];
    };
  };
});
```

Now you have a class which can be injected in order to create a lense which contains all of the logic for you.

You can inject it and use it anywhere you need:

```
function MyController($scope, Lense) {
  var data = [ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ];
  $scope.lense = Lense(data);
}
```

Then your views become a lot more declarative:

```
<p class="title text-center">{{lense.value().title}}</p>
<p class="subtitle text-center">{{lense.value().sub_title}}</p>
<a ng-click='lense.previous()'>Previous</a>
<a ng-click='lense.next()'>Next</a>
```

Not only that, but it is a lot easier to write unit tests for factories than it is for directives, as they involve no rendering on HTML.

Finally, it will be a lot easier to debug. Say you want to print the value of the current index every time the user clicks next, you can just add it to your lense factory.

```
lense.next = function() {
  lense.index += 1;
  console.log(lense);
};
```

If your logic is embedded in an expression, then there's no way to do this, because console isn't a property on the current $scope.

```
<div ng-click='index++ && console.log(index)'></div>
```

Comment: I definitely agree that if you want to make a robust, reusable component, this is a great way to go about it. There is a time a place for a quick one off, though.

Comment: Yep, nevertheless it's always good to see both ends of the spectrum.

Comment: @DanPrince Thanks for this, I agree with you but I needed a quick solution since I am making a small demo for a company. I accepted Dylan's answer because he was first and it was exactly what I was looking for, but this is extremely useful too.